# Lollipop VMs in Genymotion - possibly ARM Translation not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

I'm using Eclipse and Genymotion on mac (Yosemite). I updated Genymotion to 2.3.1 recently and created 2 Lollipop VMs: a Google Nexus 5 and a Google Nexus 7. I used ARM Translation on all of the previous VMs, and it worked fine, but on Lollipop VMs it just doesn't. I installed it on Nexus 5 as usual, it warned me about possibly corrupting the device, then installed without problems and told me that it's been successfully flashed. Then I restarted the VM as usual. When I turned it back on and tried to run my app on it, it told me this:

```
[2014-12-29 16:29:42 - app-name] ------------------------------
[2014-12-29 16:29:42 - app-name] Android Launch!
[2014-12-29 16:29:42 - app-name] adb is running normally.
[2014-12-29 16:29:42 - app-name] Performing com.example.appname.StartActivity activity launch
[2014-12-29 16:29:42 - app-name] Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
[2014-12-29 16:29:47 - app-name] Uploading app-name.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
[2014-12-29 16:29:50 - app-name] Installing app-name.apk...
[2014-12-29 16:29:51 - app-name] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
[2014-12-29 16:29:51 - app-name] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-12-29 16:29:51 - app-name] Launch canceled!
```

The logcat was empty. I tried running my app on a couple older VMs, and there were no issues.

I restarted Nexus 5 several times, installed ARM Translation again, updated SDK, rebooted ADB, rebooted computer, but the result was still the same.

For reference, when I tried (just to test what would happen) running my app on Nexus 7 where I didn't install ARM Translation, it told me the exact same thing as Nexus 5 where the ARM Translation was supposed to be installed successfully, but apparently doesn't work.

What am I missing?

UPD: I've just installed Android Studio, and it's the same there.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: genymotion-google_nexus_5___5_0_0___api_21___1080x1920-192.168.56.102:5555
Uploading file
local path: /Users/usr/AndroidstudioProjects/app-name/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.appname
Installing com.example.appname
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.appname"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.appname
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
```

So at least I can be sure that it's not an IDE problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Having the same issue here.

Comment: @Lo-Tan Not really. My colleague did some black magic (added libraries from our custom video player to the project), and the VMs started working on his computer, but when I did the same, my project crashed at compile.

Comment: I'm using Spotify's JNI library.  I guess I could compile it for the other platform this VM is trying to run, but I don't know how much I care to continue trying.  I'll stick with a real device for now :(

Comment: @Lo-Tan Me too. As much as it helps to test on different devices, it's eating up too much of my work time trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS is when you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7 and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel architecture instead it will not work